# how to make exoplayer2 use H264 codec instead of H265 in Kotlin Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, rtsp, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying o create a rtsp stream with the exoplayer2 (release 2.18.5). And i am trying to force the player to use H264. It does not work with the MimeType, because the player overwrites it somehow and uses H265 instead. I think i have to request the codec format before or i have to edit the response body in order to get the codec H264.

resonse.body of the RTSP Stream:

```
...
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 35
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:102 H265/90000
...
```

this is the code for the exoplayer setup:

```
val url = cameraInfo.cameraURLScheme
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()

        // Build the media items.
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder().setMimeType(MimeTypes.VIDEO_H264)
            .setUri(url)
            .build()
    
        val mediaSource = RtspMediaSource.Factory().createMediaSource(mediaItem)
    
        // Add the media items to be played.
        player.addMediaSource(mediaSource)
        // Prepare the player.
        player.prepare()
        // Start the playback.
        player.play()
```

Sidenote: I cannot use the H265 because it does not have the sprop-vps parameter

I have already tried to set the Mimetype and i debugged it and the mediaEncoder was still H265.
i get the followig exception

Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing sprop-vps parameter

because it uses H265 Format.

UPDATE:
I created a MediaCodecSelector but the MediaEncoder is still H265:

```
class H264MediaCodecSelector : MediaCodecSelector {
    override fun getDecoderInfos(
        mimeType: String,
        requiresSecureDecoder: Boolean,
        requiresTunnelingDecoder: Boolean
    ): MutableList<MediaCodecInfo> {
        Log.d("H264MediaCodecSelector", "getDecoderInfos called")

        val codecInfoList = MediaCodecUtil.getDecoderInfos(mimeType, requiresSecureDecoder, requiresTunnelingDecoder)
        val filteredCodecInfo = mutableListOf<MediaCodecInfo>()
        for (codecInfo in codecInfoList) {
            if (!blacklistedCodec(codecInfo.name.lowercase(Locale.US))){
                filteredCodecInfo.add(codecInfo)
            }
        }

        return filteredCodecInfo
    }


    private fun blacklistedCodec(codecName : String) : Boolean{
        if (codecName.contains(MimeTypes.VIDEO_H265)){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}



 val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).setRenderersFactory(DefaultRenderersFactory(context).setMediaCodecSelector(H264MediaCodecSelector())).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a custom implementation of `MediaCodecSelector` where you can exclude a decoder for the particular mime type. Then pass it to the player using `DefaultRenderersFactory`:

```
    ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
        .setRenderersFactory(DefaultRenderersFactory(this)
            .setMediaCodecSelector(YourMediaCodecSelector()))
        .build()
```

Comment: how can i create a MediaCodecSelector for H264?

Comment: `class H264MediaCodecSelector : MediaCodecSelector {
    override fun getDecoderInfos(
        mimeType: String,
        requiresSecureDecoder: Boolean,
        requiresTunnelingDecoder: Boolean
    ): MutableList<MediaCodecInfo> {
        if (mimeType == MimeTypes.VIDEO_H265) {
            return mutableListOf()
        }
        return MediaCodecUtil.getDecoderInfos(mimeType, requiresSecureDecoder, requiresTunnelingDecoder)
    }`

 what would your solution look like?

Comment: Does it work for you? Here is an example usage https://github.com/fgl27/SmartTwitchTV/blob/master/apk/app/src/main/java/com/fgl27/twitch/BlackListMediaCodecSelector.java

Comment: i updated the main Question could you please take a look?

Comment: Are you sure that blacklistedCodec works properly? Can you log and share the list of codecs?